# Android studio : Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK

Tags: java, android

I've made a modification in my code by adding a second activity and now I have this error :

```
01/20 07:14:24: Launching 'app' on 10.1  WXGA (Tablet) API 26.
    Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed:
    INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK
    List of apks: [0]
    'C:\Users\Moi\Desktop\EscapeGameSTW\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
    The application's minSdkVersion is newer than the device API level.
```

The AndroidiManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="true" />

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.5.0'

}
```

The deviceSDK I have to use is API26.

I've deleted the modifications, but the error still occurs.
I've tried to change the compileSdkVersion to 26
How can I resume this error ?

Thanks every body.

Comment: Please note that I resolved the issue by simply downloading a newer version of the SDK.  Simply go to `Tools`->`SDK Manager` and download a newer version.  Didn't find the linked answer to that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've found my problem. It was due to the library wearable. After removing it, everything runs well

```
<uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
        android:required="true" />
```

Max

Answer (score 1):

Your mobile `API level` is lower than your project's minimum Sdk version

In gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
    //You have to decrease the minSdkVersion cause, your android's API level is lower than this. minSdkVersion used for from which API level of android you can use
    minSdkVersion 27
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

So, try

```
minSdkVersion 20
```

if possible Cause, it must be compatible with your source code also. Just change it depending on your android's API level